# How to make WebStorm indent es6 object literals correctly?

Tags: ide, indentation, pycharm, webstorm, ecmascript-6

In es6, you can create an object with a function as one of its members as follows:

```
var foo = {
    doStuff(a, r, g, s){
        // do some stuff here.
    }
};
```

But WebStorm (actually PyCharm, but [according to JetBrains, PyCharm does everything WebStorm does](https://twitter.com/WebStormIDE/status/437667183381196800)), doesn't indent what's inside the function, and dedents the closing curly brace. I've entered `es6` and various variations into the search field in preferences, but all that comes up are inspections, where I've already enabled es6 features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works fine for me in webStorm 9, 10 EAP and PyCharm 4.0.5 EAP. 
Please make sure to set JavaScript Language Version to `'ECMAScript 6'` in `Preferences/Languages&Frameworks/JavaScript`